# Is Atman really Brahman?

Tags: atma, brahman, advaita, adi-shankaracharya

Recently I am going through Adhvaita Vedhanta.

It is said that brahman present in every one's body as Athman. Athman is nothing but consciousness.

May be at the time of Adi Shankara, science is not this much advance, so he thought of Brahman, consciousness etc. But if you see the current science, the consciousness that we are experiencing is because of our brain, nerves, spinal cord etc. All these body parts are responsible for our consciousness according to science. These body parts will die once the person dies means the consciousness will not exist after that person dies. It is clear from science. Sorry if my understanding on Advaitha is completely wrong :) . I am just a beginner to it.

Do you really think that there is still Brahman and Athman? Advaitha also claims that all our puranas, vedas, ramayana, maha bharatha etc are not real and just myths. Is there any thing that is still left to believe in god?

If I wont ask this question, someone in future may ask, we as hindus need to provide strong reasons.

I strongly oppose other religions influence on Hinduism, so asking this question to have clear thoughts.

Also please name few who attained moksha by realizing Athman as Brahman. Did Adi Shankara attained it?

Comment: No, Advaita Vedanta has never said Mahabharata, Puranas and Ramayana are wrong. Why would Shankara then quote from these in his works? Also, that would mean Bhagavad Gita (which is a part of Mahabharata) is false which is one of the most important texts in Advaita Vedanta.

Comment: Also, its a misconception among people that Advaita Vedanta says the world is unreal. The world is real, but not as real as the Self. See: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19930/world-is-real-even-according-to-advait-vedanta?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I recommend you search and read about this specific phrase: "hard problem of consciousness".  'Science' or more accurately philosophy of physicalism can not yet understand or explain consciousness.

Comment: Read Swami Vivekananda commentary on Patanjali Yoga Sutras. He says mind is also just instrument of Atma (Consciousness). Regarding Science, Science evolves rapidly.

Comment: Where have you found that "Atman is nothing but consciousness" in Advaita scriptures? Regarding unreality of universe, I suggest to go through [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13596/277)

Comment: thank you all for responses, also could you guide what to do to get liberation in advaitha?